# Difference between calling method on it vs reference inside ?.let body

Tags: android, kotlin

Is any difference between method calls on it vs reference value inside ?.let body ?

```
fun setDrawableTintColor(drawable: Drawable?, @ColorInt tintColor: Int) {
    drawable?.let {
        drawable.mutate()
        if (tintColor != COLOR_NO_TINT) {
            drawable.setColorFilter(tintColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
        } else {
            drawable.clearColorFilter()
        }
    }
}
```

And this one:

```
fun setDrawableTintColor(drawable: Drawable?, @ColorInt tintColor: Int) {
    drawable?.let {
        it.mutate()
        if (tintColor != COLOR_NO_TINT) {
            it.setColorFilter(tintColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
        } else {
            it.clearColorFilter()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no there is no real difference

Comment: I wouldn't use `let` if you don't plan to use the given parameter of the block (except in the case were you deliberately ignore it)... it seems to me that you are better off just writing `if (drawable != null) {/* what was in your let-block */ }`. Maybe mixing those two can become ugly if you nest several blocks inside each other or if someone decides using both, `it` and `drawable`, in the same block... but who knows... never mixed it and don't plan to do so...

Answer (score 0):

Both are same, Either of below you can use

(1)

```
fun setDrawableTintColor(drawable: Drawable?, @ColorInt tintColor: Int) {
    drawable?.let {
        drawable.mutate()
        if (tintColor != COLOR_NO_TINT) {
            drawable.setColorFilter(tintColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
        } else {
            drawable.clearColorFilter()
        }
    }
}
```

(2)

```
fun setDrawableTintColor(drawable: Drawable?, @ColorInt tintColor: Int) {
    drawable?.let {
        it.mutate()
        if (tintColor != COLOR_NO_TINT) {
            it.setColorFilter(tintColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
        } else {
            it.clearColorFilter()
        }
    }
}
```

(3)

```
fun setDrawableTintColor(drawable: Drawable?, @ColorInt tintColor: Int) {
    drawable?.let { drawableRes ->
        drawableRes.mutate()
        if (tintColor != COLOR_NO_TINT) {
            drawableRes.setColorFilter(tintColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
        } else {
            drawableRes.clearColorFilter()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Kotlin feature, the first way is changing directly object, in the second way changing argument passed [scope-functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html#let).

when using let function generally better than use self object (mean it).
compiler when compiling a code understands it is a reference this objet.
int other way, when compiling a code compiler first running value.